# Android chat/MUD client - WCF or Socket viable?

Tags: android, wcf, sockets

I am trying to create a text-based multiplayer game for android (similar to oldschool MUDs). I currently have a basic wcf service working - I can make a request on my android app and my server responds with a blob of xml data.

However, I am unsure if this is a workable strategy down the road - if using WCF, I would be limited app side by the number and frequency of requests I could make to the server. A socket connection would seem to provide the fully duplex communication I need but I am unsure how to implement this (and I've read Android may not support this duplex socket communication as I describe?). In any case, guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

How frequently could I reasonably hope to poll my WCF service from an android phone on 3g? Is this fast enough for something like chat between multiple users through a server?

Is there some android socket code I can look into? Can I host my own socket server using either visual studio (IIS?) or eclipse?

Comment: I've had some issue with WCF and large chunks of data. The only solution I found was to tweak the WCF configuration on both server and client, but obviously that would be problematic with non-Windows clients.  (IMHO that's a ridiculous limitation for a Web service framework.)

Comment: when you say 'large chunks of data' what do you mean roughly? the response xml object my WCF service is returning might have something on the order of 50 strings and 50 ints when it is completely fleshed out.

Comment: We exceeded the default `maxReceivedMessageSize` which I believe was 64K.  We were transmitting up to a few megabytes at a time.  Note that `maxBufferSize` and `maxBufferPoolSize` default to the same value as `maxReceivedMessageSize` -- or at least they used to -- so you'll need to bump those up too.  
(I may be a little off here, it's been more than a year...  But if you Google WCF plus any of those configuration parameter names, you'll get a number of hits on SO and elsewhere.)